# how to zip files from url and then return zip file as response in flask

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, zip

---

```
def generate_files_link():
    url = 'https://www.facebook.com/favicon.ico'
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    z=zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
    return Response( z,mimetype='application/zip',headers={'Content-Disposition': 
                         'attachment;filename=files.zip'})
```

**output**

```
raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the [`ZipFile.writestr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr) method from the zipfile module as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10450523/9254757) to convert a string to a zip file.

```py
def generate_files_link():
    url = 'https://www.facebook.com/favicon.ico'
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    print(r.content)
    z = zipfile.ZipFile.writestr(
        zinfo_or_arcname="files.zip", data=io.BytesIO(r.content))
    return Response(z, mimetype='application/zip', headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=files.zip'})
```